# How do I make my tank track tread spin?

Tags: rigging

[[image: the file model working ]the file model working [1]] (the file model working ^^^^^)this is my model bellow (1)
[image]
[image: my attempt at translating your work]

(my attempt at translating your work ^^^^)I want it too spin like in this Youtube video tutorial(2)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve something like that with drivers.
-add a driver on the Y value of your track object.
-open the graph editor and add a `Transform Channel` driver type like in pic below.
-select the object in "Ob/bone" field that you want to copy the scale value from, I used the default cube's Z Scale channel.
now scaling the cube will spin your Track.

(*I don't know how to prevent the scaling of the cube.*)

[image]

Here is a blend file, I hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: When I tried it on the file you gave me it worked but when I translated it into my own model it wouldn`t work I have retraced my steps everything seems fine I don`t know why it wont work?

Comment: I have added two gifs to demonstrate

Comment: can you upload a blend file with the model in it?

Comment: here is the file @R00t [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1368" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1368/)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make mesh spin like that, from the sceenshot in your question i thought it's a simple mesh with an array modifer that follows a curve but your model is one applied object. I tried for a good hour and couldn't get it to work like you wanted, if you don't have the mesh before the array and curve modifiers applied , a suggestion would be to extract a repeating mesh from the trank with a boolean modifier , make a curve that follows the same outline like the original and make the mesh your extracted follow that curve. [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pA8AP.png).

Comment: Alright I will try the way you suggested I have been stuck with this for a bout a week now,

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer. Translate the tank tracks, instead of rotating them.

Yours sincerely,