# How can I rotate these tracks perfectly?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

So I am trying to create tracks for a Tiger H1 Heavy Tank. I've created a baseline for the tracks so far, my only problem is that I want to rotate the tracks around the wheel/tires perfectly while maintaining the same distance from each other.

[image]

I could potentially use a modifier for this, does anyone know what's the ideal modifier that I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: Also advanced Tank track Rig with simulation here to look into: https://www.blendswap.com/blend/8861

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my tank track tread spin?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53733/how-do-i-make-my-tank-track-tread-spin)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier